# Thermal noise typical values

Tags: noise, thermal

I am curious to know what thermal noise waveforms look like in the time domain. Most of the analysis is based on probability.  What is the typical voltage amplitude of thermal noise in let's say a 1000 ohm resistor at 100 Hz, assuming it's connected to nothing? Has it been ever measured experimentally?  if we could connect it to an ideal scope that can measure voltages up to nanovolts, and very high-frequency resolution can we see it? I wonder if this can be ever used as a power source someday. Like if something could absorb thermal noise, it could theoretically work as a power generating cooler

Answer (score 0):

There's a equation giving this voltage on the wikipedia page.  Just plug in your numbers.

[Noise Voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise#Noise_voltage_and_power)

The voltage waveforms would be basically random white noise.  Every frequency, though likely some would be favored depending on the nature of the device - That's way beyond my mastery of the subject though.

'Absorbing the noise' in your idea is absorbing heat.  The noise is generated by the random motion of atoms.  The average speed of the atoms is what gives something its temperature. If you want to reduce noise, you reduce the speed of the atoms, reduce the number of random collisions -- you reduce it's temperature. CMOS sensors in observatory telescopes are cooled to crazy low temperatures so they don't generate thermal noise -- not a good thing when you're trying to capture photons coming from 4,000,000,000,000 light years away!   Anyhow - THis is how you do it  [Seebeck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect)    It works if you're moving heat from a high temperature zone to a lower temperature zone... if you want to move heat the other way, you have to put energy into the system (i.e. make something cooler than it's surroundings).  You can never get away from the laws of physics unfortunately  :(